# iPod classic not recognized by Windows 10

Tags: drivers, reinstall, ipod

I have a 6th generation (latest) iPod classic. 
It was perfectly recognized by Windows 10 until a few weeks ago.

Now when I plug it in my pc nothing happens (the iPod enters charging status but no sync and the device does not appears in Explorer).

I did several device reset and recovery mode trials, with no effect until I found the solution.

In devices manager the ipod driver was marked with the triangle and exclamation mark icon. I removed the device, searched for new devices and a working driver appeared.

My problem is that I must do this device manager tour every time because if I close windows and reconnect the iPod the driver has again the triangle and the iPod is not recognized.

Do you have a suggestion to make Windows "remember" the correct driver and prevent this "reinstall driver" loop?

Comment: You have itunes installed?

Comment: Also see this....https://www.technipages.com/itunes-fix-iphone-or-ipod-not-detected-in-windows

Comment: @Moab, yes I have iTunes, if I see the iPod in Windows Explorer then iTunes recognises it as well, otherwise nothing happens. I'll try this week the other trick you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I had my iPod Classic connected in a USB 3.0 port and it did not register at all in Windows Explorer (W10) or in iTunes. I moved it to one of the 2.0 ports and ta-daa!

Comment: This right here, on the first try with a rockbox ipod nano gen2. Itunes asked to download and install software right away (might be due to changing assigned driver on my part, nonetheless...).